# include one mouseover into a div created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have one script  :

```
        if (el.tags.includes(selectedTag)) {
            const itemsContent = document.createElement('div');
            itemsContent.className = 'items-content';
            const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
            h2.className = 'project-title';
            h2.innerHTML = el.title;
            div.appendChild(h2);
            main.appendChild(div);
        }
```

And i want to be able to add a mouseover in my 'itemsContent' div

to generate something like :

```
<div onmouseover="onProjectHover(...)"  class="items-content"> My content</div>
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
`itemsContent.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (event)){ 
// your event handler code goes here
 })`

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

Comment: i removed one ) after event but that's the solution thanks